# How to call function in .vb file via aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, docusignapi

I have created webform aspx file and I have a button to generate pdf then upload to my form. When I click submit button, need to call a function in vb file like a CreateEnvelpoeAPI for DocuSign. Anyway, how to call a function via aspx page?

```
//form.aspx.vb
Protected Sub btSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btSubmit.Click
    Response.Redirect("CreateEnvelopeAPI.vb") // I expecte to call function n in here.
End Sub

// CreateEnvelopeAPI.vb
Public Class CreateEnvelopeAPI

Public Function Init() As String
    Dim username As String = ""
    Dim password As String = ""
    Dim integratorKey As String = ""

    ' initialize client for desired environment (for production change to www)
    Dim apiClient As New ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi")
    Configuration.[Default].ApiClient = apiClient

    ' configure 'X-DocuSign-Authentication' header
    Dim authHeader As String = (Convert.ToString((Convert.ToString((Convert.ToString("{""Username"":""") & username) + """, ""Password"":""") & password) + """, ""IntegratorKey"":""") & integratorKey) + """}"
    Configuration.[Default].AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader)

    ' we will retrieve this from the login API call
    Dim accountId As String = Nothing

    '''//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ' STEP 1: LOGIN API        
    '''//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ' login call is available in the authentication api 
    Dim authApi As New AuthenticationApi()
    Dim loginInfo As LoginInformation = authApi.Login()

    ' parse the first account ID that is returned (user might belong to multiple accounts)
    accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts(0).AccountId

    ' Update ApiClient with the new base url from login call
    apiClient = New ApiClient(loginInfo.LoginAccounts(0).BaseUrl)

    Return accountId
End Function
Public Sub CreateEnvelopeAPI()
    Dim accountId As String = Init()

    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes("Invoice.pdf")

    Dim envDef = New EnvelopeDefinition()
    envDef.EmailSubject = "[DocuSign C# SDK] - Custom Fields"
    envDef.Status = "sent"


    envDef.CustomFields = New CustomFields()

    Dim textCustomField = New TextCustomField()
    textCustomField.Name = "TransactionId"
    textCustomField.Value = "KTI456"

    Dim textCustomFields = New List(Of TextCustomField)()
    textCustomFields.Add(textCustomField)
    envDef.CustomFields.TextCustomFields = textCustomFields

    ' Add a recipient to sign the documeent
    Dim signer As New Signer()
    signer.Email = ""
    signer.Name = ""
    signer.RecipientId = "1"

    signer.Tabs = New Tabs()
    signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = New List(Of SignHere)()

    Dim signHereTab = New SignHere()
    signHereTab.DocumentId = "1"
    signHereTab.PageNumber = "1"
    signHereTab.XPosition = "100"
    signHereTab.YPosition = "100"
    signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHereTab)

    envDef.Recipients = New Recipients()
    envDef.Recipients.Signers = New List(Of Signer)()
    envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer)

    ' Add a document to the envelope
    Dim doc As New Document()
    doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes)
    doc.Name = "Invoice.pdf"
    doc.DocumentId = "1"

    envDef.Documents = New List(Of Document)()
    envDef.Documents.Add(doc)


    Dim envelopesApi As New EnvelopesApi()
    Dim envelopeSummary As EnvelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef)
    Console.WriteLine(envelopeSummary)
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You call a function just like any other function in VB. The fact it's in the context of an ASP.NET page makes no difference to that.

```
Protected Sub btSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btSubmit.Click
    Dim api = new CreateEnvelopeAPI() 'instantiate the class
    api.CreateEnvelopeAPI() 'call a function
End Sub
```

(N.B. This is assuming that the CreateEnvelopeAPI.vb file is part of your project, and that the class is in the same namespace. If either of those is not the case, then you just need to include the file and/or add an `Imports` statement to include the namespace in your aspx code.)

P.S. Response.Redirect is used if you want to send the browser to another page (i.e. a another HTTP URL), not to call a function within your code.